# how copy marker location in leaflet

Tags: copy, location

i have a map leaflet and show on map marker whit lat,lug.

how now create location link from marker lat,lug ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNcMG.png)

i for create link used this code :

```
if (navigator && navigator.clipboard && navigator.clipboard.writeText)
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(
          `https://maps.google.com/?q=${this.orderInfo.latitude},${this.orderInfo.longitude}`
        );
```